# Adding a new data into a char array of readings

Tags: c, arrays, string, freertos

I'm designing the firmware for ESP32 using the ESP-IDF and FreeRTOS. 
I want to convert the reading of a sensor into a char array and store it in the Non-Volatile Storage. When a new reading is taken, it is to be added to the front of the char array pushing the older readings to the right.

I'm doing the array manipulation in this way:

```
#define MAX_BYTES 100
char oldData[MAX_BYTES];
char newData[15];
sprintf(newData, "%.2f", Totalmass);
strcat(newData, ",");
int newlen = strlen(newData);
int looper = (sizeof(oldData) - newlen - 1);
for(int i = looper; i >= 0; i--)    {
    oldData[i + newlen] = oldData[i];
}
looper = strlen(newData);
for(int i = 0; i < looper; i++) {
    oldData[i] = newData[i];
}
printf("strlen final Data:\n", strlen(oldData));
printf("Final Data: %s\n", oldData);
```

Now coming to the problem I'm facing:

After the length of oldData exceeds 100 i.e, MAX_BYTES, the length of oldData is 100 + the length of the newest reading. On printing my final array, I see that the newest data, gets concatenated to the front(which is desirable), but it also adds to the end of the array. This is probably why my data length exceeds by MAX_BYTES by the length of my newest data.

OUTPUT:

```
strlen final Data: 112
Final Data: -3129344.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2796202.00,-8388604.00,133152.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,-3129344.00,
```

If you'll see the above output, the length exceeds MAX_BYTES by 12, which is the length of the latest reading i.e, "-3129344.00,". And that data occurs in the array in the beginning as well as the end of the array.

1. Why is this unwanted behavior occuring? Can anyone notice if I'm doing something wrong?
2. This question is just for my curiosity. Why isnt the array overflowing even if the length exceeds its size? I noticed that the code crashed earlier when it exceeds the size by a larger amount.

Thanks in advance for anyone going through my question!

Comment: I'd use [`memmove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) for moving the array content. And also I'd store the readings in float format, that will probably be much easier to handle.

Comment: 1) Can you store the reading in ```float```s? 2) Can you use a circullar buffer? As I understand, you are only interested in newest data, so circullar buffer should do the trick.

Comment: Are you copying the terminating 0 in the first for loop? Also, why are you calculating `strlen(newdata)` on each loop iteration? It's not changing.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Would using "memmove" be a suitable way to remove and concatenate parts of the array? Could you please give an example on how to do so?

Comment: @Melon since the mobile app accepts string data, the data cannot be stored as float. And I'm also interested in the past data. Would be a lot simpler if a dynamic size of array wasn't to be considered though.

Comment: @doug The length of the latest data is dynamic and could change according to the data read from the sensors. The "OUTPUT" I've shown above in the question says it.

Comment: "The length of the latest data is dynamic "  It is not dynamic inside the first for loop so it's a waste of CPU steps to recalculate it each iteration of the loop. That said, it's not an error.

Comment: @doug Oh, right. That would be my bad. I've corrected it. Thanks